# $V$ is finite dimensional if and only if all linear operators $T\colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ are continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, linear-transformations

Where $V$ is a a normed $\mathbb{K}$-vector space ($\mathbb{K}$ = $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ ). I have showed right implication. I believe I also showed ($\Leftarrow$) but it seems too easy, so I think I might be missing something. Here is the reasoning.

We assume $V$ is infinite dimensional, then we can easily construct a linear and non-bounded operator, and hence non continuous. Let $B = \{ e_1, e_2,\dots, \}$ be a basis of $V$. Let $z \in V$, so we have $z = \sum_i \alpha_i e_i$. We define

\begin{equation}
T(z) = \sum_i \alpha_i
\end{equation}

Then $T$ is linear, but for say $z = \sum_i e_i$, we have $\lVert z\rVert_V < \infty$ and $\lVert T(z)\rVert = \infty$

Comment: Did you perhaps say "finite" where you meant "infinite", and *vice versa*?

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment because it refers to an edited part of the post. However, I must still point out that $z$ is ill defined. A base $B$ of a vector space is such if every element of the space can be written as a **finite** linear combination of elements in $B$. For all we know that sum may not converge to an element of $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your statement is the opposite of the correct one: $V$ is finite-dimensional if and only if every linear map from $V$ into $\mathbb K$ is continuous.

Your proof is wrong. How can you possibly $\|T(z)\|=\infty$? The norm of a vector is always a non-negative real number and $\infty$ is not a number.

---

Your proof is wrong for another reason: there is no such thing as $\sum_ie_i$. This sum diverges in general.

Comment: Ok, I think I made a typo and someone edited the question in the wrong way by mistake. Im proving that if $V$ is infinite dimensional then we do not have that all linear operators are bounded.